# Go moq : running "moq": exec: "moq": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: linux, go, path, mocking

when trying the example of the moq framework, I get the following exception when I enter "go generate":

> example.go:5: running "moq": exec: "moq": executable file not found in $PATH

What should I do? I'm using Kubuntu 16.04

PS: I tried

> export PATH=$PATH:/home/[...]/go/src/github.com/matryer/moq

without success

Comment: set your path like this - export PATH=$PATH:/home/[...]/go/bin. do verify that the moq execute file exists in /go/bin directory. If not exist, go to the src/github.com/matryer/moq and compile the src.

Comment: What @sprabhakaran said. But make sure you've used `go install`, not `go build`. That is, do `go install github.com/matryer/moq`

Comment: I also needed to add `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` to make the script work. Source : https://github.com/matryer/moq/issues/29

Comment: @sprabhakaran, Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sprabhakaran got the right answer. I only needed to add the go binary folder to the PATH global variable:

> export PATH=$PATH:/home/[...]/go/bin

and if it doesn't work, check that moq was correctly installed.

Comment: What if you're using go modules?

Answer (score 2):

First, install using the following command:

```bash
go install github.com/matryer/moq@latest
```

Go binary should be added to the global `PATH`

```bash
 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```

worked for me on MAC